# Modify animated Armature BGE

Tags: animation, game-engine, armature

I have an armature which has animation. To play my animation in BGE I added an `Always Sensor`  `AND`ed it to `Action actuator` and set it's value to the animation. It plays good. But what I'm trying to do is rotate some of the bones during the animation using the keyboard with Python which doesn't work only if the armature didn't have any animation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action actuator will play the animation of the action. This animation consists of several channels. On armature actions these channels are the channels of the single bones. Typical channels are location, rotation, scale.

When the animation plays a channel it sets the pose of the bone regardless what pose the bone had before.

When you want to pose the channel via Python you should ensure this channel is not set within the action otherwise it gets overridden (the animation gets applied after the Python controller set the pose).

## Solution

Remove all channels you want to manipulate via Python from within the action

[image]

## Hint

When you play two actions that share the same channel only one of the actions will be played (unless

Comment: Could you please have a look at my question here http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/66536/2517